# Using result of Stored Procedure with dynamic query in another Stored Procedure with dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I runned into a problem while creating a stored procedure that uses user-defined types and builds a dynamic query that is to be executed on the end of the stored procedure.
I have done this before, but this time it is different. I am building a dynamic aggregated SELECT statement that has to (dynamically) invoke another stored procedure and use the results inline.

Since that other stored procedure also uses dynamic SQL, it cannot be defined in a user-defined function.

I will now show an example of the problem in SQL code, hope it helps.

First stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP1]
...--(some uder defined types)
AS
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
...--(some cursors used in assembling the dynamic query)
...--(at some point I have a check whether there are additional filter criteria)
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + '(SELECT COUNT([Column]) FROM [TableX]';
IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) FilterCriteria FROM @additionalCriteriaTable))
BEGIN
  SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery = 'AND [IdOfTableX] IN (EXEC [dbo].[SP2] @param1, @param2 ...)';
END
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ')';
```

And stored procedure 2 is used to determine which rows of [TableX] conform any given criteria, also using some cursors and a dynamic query. SP2 returns the IDS of these rows.

So cleary I am going about this in the wrong way, since you cannot select from a stored procedure inline. You can however from a user defined function but there you cannot use dynamic SQL which I need.
Is there maybe a way so that results of a stored procedure CAN be used inline, maybe by using a form of annotation that defines that the stored procedure only returns a specific result set?

I hope some of you can help me,

Cheers Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it better to have the calling stored procedure create a temporary table which is then populated in the nested call. It doesn't have to be a global table to be visible but you can't create it inside SP2 or it will disappear before SP1 has a chance to refer to it.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up with. I ran into the problem that INSERT EXEC statements could not be nested so I created a temporary table in SP1, which SP2 then fills. After this I join the id column into a NVARCHAR.

I will mark this as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the result of the stored procedure in a temporary table and use that table later in the query.

Something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @additionalCriteriaTable)
BEGIN
  SET @SQLQuery = '
    CREATE TABLE #temp ... 
    INSERT INTO #temp EXEC [dbo].[SP2] @param1, @param2 ...' 
    + @SQLQuery + ' AND [IdOfTableX] IN (SELECT Something FROM #temp)';
END
```

You just have to be careful to create the temporary table with exactly the same structure as the result of the stored procedure (you cannot omit any columns or change the order of the columns).

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, however since this check occurs in a cursor, the values in #temp will change often.

Comment: I also wanted to avoid multiple stages of execution, but it seems this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is you want:

```
In your code:

SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery = 'AND [IdOfTableX] IN (EXEC [dbo].[SP2] @param1, @param2 ...)';
```

the @sqlquery will not be built correctly.